# missing xamarin.googleplayservices references

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use google maps on my xamarin forms application. I installed Google.forms.maps. With that installation, I got below packages:

```
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="42.1021.1"    targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

As soon as I start running the application, these dll's go away from android project reference and I get the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks'   app1.Android

Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base'    app1.Android    
Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'    app1.Android
Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basemant'    app1.Android
```

I googled for this error and tried to add these packages separately using nuget so I did this

```
Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base -Version 60.1142.0
```

I got an error saying

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any
```

assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

so I tried doing this:

```
Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base -Version 29.0.0.1
```

I got the same error as I got with nuget package version 60.1142.0

I am using Visual studio 2017 enterprise version.

any help in this regards will be appreciated. Below are the target for android project:

[image]

[image]

My target framework is like this:

[image]

and The sdk Picture is like this:

[image]

Below is the visual studio Help-> about window.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic message:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.XXXXXXX'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=vX.X'

Specific message:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1'

Change your `Xamarin.Android`project to target at least `MonoAndroid 8.0` as `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` v60.1142.0 has a dependency on 8.0

[image]

#### Nuget: [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base/60.1142.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base/60.1142.0)

#### Dependencies

[image]

Comment: I don't see the monoAndroid 8.0 in the android target project. I posted the picture above

Comment: Then you either have an older version of xamarin installed 
and or do not have your Android sdk updated

Comment: I need little bit more help here. I have the picture of SDK and Target framework selection. Can you please look at that and suggest what I am missing. I think I am looking at the wrong place

Comment: What version of visual studio do you have installed and open your andriod sdk manager and check if you have 8.0  and 8.1 installed

Comment: I had 8.1 installed and I didn't have 8.0 installed. I just installed 8.0 in SDK manager when I saw your comment I have Ms visual studio enterprise 2017 and .net framework version 4.7.02046. I still don't see monoAndroid 8.0 in the target project

Comment: @Anjali What version of VS 2017?

Comment: The version is 15.0.0. I also put the Help->about in my original post. I can update the version if there is newer version

Comment: @Anjali Android 8.0 support was not added until 15.4.2:  https://releases.xamarin.com/service-release-15-4-2/

Comment: Thank You. I will upgrade to 15.4.2. Thank you again for all your help!!