# Xamarin - Updating nuget packages caused errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a "Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms)" app, and i immediately went and update the nuget packages (this is what i was told to do). Then i tried to built it, and not only I got several errors(see bellow) that were about the updated packages, I had code errors as well. I swear the God that i didn't touch the code of the project at all, and here is what I get:

[image]

I googled, but i couldn't find out a clean solution for this. I am just one step before quitting this (unprofessional) product, because i cannot run the ready template. Is there someone that can give me a piece of advice for these ridiculous errors ?

Comment: You need to increase your "Target Framework" to at least 7.0 as the error indicates, much like this error that requires at least MonoDroid 8.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138485/4984832 (And do not use images for errors, paste the errors as formatted text directly into your question so they are indexable/searchable/readable on mobile, etc..)

Comment: Yes! Actually you were right. I don't know why everything is so problematic regarding Xamarin. So many issues ... anyway, thank you very much! If you want post it as a solution, in order for me to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.XXXXXXX'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=vX.X'

[image]

You need to increase your "Compile Target Framework" to at least 7.0 as this error indicates.

You can review the dependancies of a package on the Nuget.org site by looking at the `Dependencies` section of a particular package:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/

Another SO question/answer example that requires at least MonoDroid 8.0:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138485/4984832

#### Example:

`Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.x.x` requires at least `MonoAndroid 8.1` to be set as the **Compile Target Framework**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use newer android SDK version. You can download the SDK from android SDK manager and then select it from project properties