# Can't update or install Facebook.Android package in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As the title says, I can't install Facebook.Android package or update

- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter

Error message: Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject.Android'.

Earlier this day I had another issue, I got "Access to the path "xamarin.forms.build.tasks.dll" is denied." I couldn't even clean the cache, I had to manually delete that file to be able to restore packages. Then, I could update Xamarin.Forms, FreshMVVM, but not the mentioned Android packages.

What can I do or how can i get a detailed error report?

Another (basic) question: if I have like Facebook.Android package, I should install it for the base project and android project or for every project?

Edit: full error:

```
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 23.4.0.1 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.4.0.1) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 23.4.0.1 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.4.0.1) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 23.4.0.1 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.4.0.1) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 was resolved.
Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2 supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 27.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 27.0.2 supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 27.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 27.0.2 supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 27.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 27.0.2 supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
```

Now I understand why I get these errors when I want to update. But i still don't understand why Facebook.Android won't install.

Edit2: Android update problem log:

```
Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2) 
 MyProject.Android -> Xamarin.Facebook.Android 4.26.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 25.3.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.3.1).
```

Comment: `Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes` : What is the full error?

Comment: How can I see the full error?
Edit: Nevermind I found it. Edited the post.

Comment: It is about the dependencies, that version of `Xamarin.Facebook.Android` requires a version of the support libraries that requires a newer version of MonoDroid then your project is currently targeting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140677/xamarin-updating-nuget-packages-caused-errors/49200375#49200375  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138485/4984832