# .Net framework problem in adding google maps API with windows 10 and visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6, .net-4.7, .net-4.7.2

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author".

I need help in a downgrade or upgrade suggestions in the integration of Google Maps API in visual studio 2017.

Comment: Hi, can you improve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your package homepage is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps, you need to find out which .net framework it supports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing xamarin.googleplayservices references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138171/missing-xamarin-googleplayservices-references)